# My feedback tab will not display my code?

Tags: html, css

I have been working on my website for a while now.

My Contact Us tab is exactly the way I want it. But my feedback tab seems to not wanting to display. It was working before I put my contact us code in.

I do not know if it is my div tags that are causing the trouble or not. But I am not able to figure out what the problem is.

Could someone please explain what I did wrong?

Thanks.

Code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>{PEBKAC} - HomePage</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<style>
.w3-bar-item{
  margin-top: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}
</style>

<body style="background-color:white;">

<div class="w3-sidebar w3-bar-block w3-light-grey w3-card-2" 
style="width:130px">

  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'Home')">Home</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'Questions')">Questions</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'Search')">Search</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'Users')">Users</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'About')">About</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'Profile')">Profile</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'Settings')">Settings</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'LogOut')">Log Out</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'Terms')">Terms</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'PrivacyPolicy')">Privacy Policy</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'ContactUs')">Contact Us</button>
  <button class="w3-bar-item w3-button tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 
'Feedback')">Feedback</button>

</div>

<div style="margin-left:130px">


 <div id="Home" class="w3-container city" style="display:none"> 

  </div>

  <div id="Questions" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">

  </div>

  <div id="Search" class="w3-container city" style="display:none"> 

</div>

<div id="Users" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">

</div>

<div id="About" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">

</div>

<div id="Profile" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">

</div>

<div id="Settings" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">

</div>

<div id="LogOut" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">

</div>

<div id="Terms" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">

</div>

<div id="PrivacyPolicy" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">

</div>

<div id="ContactUs" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">

<style>

div3 {

text-align: center;
}

</style>

<div3>
<h1>{PEBKAC}</h1>
<p>_____________________________________________________________________</p>
<h2>Customer Support:</h2>

<p>Thank you for using {PEBKAC}! Please complete the form below. <br> This 
is the 
fastest and easiest way to get in touch with us.</p>

<p><b>U.S.</b></p>
<p><b> Monday-Friday 11:30 AM - 11:45 PM CST <br>
Saturday-Sunday 1:50 PM - 11:45 PM CST</b></p>

<p><b>Contact by E-mail only.</b></p>

<style>
input[type=text], select, textarea {
width: 100%;
padding: 12px;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-top: 6px;
margin-bottom: 16px;
resize: vertical;
}

input[type=submit] {
background-color: grey;
color: white;
padding: 12px 20px;
border: none;
border-radius: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
background-color: grey;
}

.container {
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<form action="mailto:the email that I choose" method="post" 
enctype="text/plain">

<div class="container">
<form action="/action_page.php">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Your 
Username..">

<label for="E-mail">E-mail:</label>
<input type="text" id="E-mail" name="E-mail" placeholder="Your E-mail..">


<label for="subject">Subject</label>
<textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Write Something.." 
style="height:200px"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
</div3>


</div>

<div id="Feedback" class="w3-container city" style="display:none">

<br> <br> <br> 

<style>

div2 {

text-align: center;
}


</style>

<div2>
<p>Giving {PEBKAC} Feedback: <br> <br> You as a user giving us suggestions 
improves {PEBKAC}! With giving us 
continuous feedback; <br> {PEBKAC} is able to come out with new features and 
services. 
Unfortunately, {PEBKAC} is not able to <br> develop every users ideas. But 
when we do; we
will make sure it is top notch quality.</p> <br>

<p>How, When, and Why: <br> <br> If you look to the left of the screen; you 
will see
a prompt. This will have you <br> enter your First Name, Last Name, E-Mail, 
and what would you like to 
leave as feedback. <br> Once you have finished, click the send button. If 
you would like to have a 
fresh start; click reset. <br> We recommend one suggestion at a time. <br> 
<br>

Once the feedback is sent; it goes to The {PEBKAC} corporation. (Where all 
the magic happens!) <br> Someone working at
{PEBKAC} will open and read the feedback. It is then presented to <br> the 
CEO of {PEBKAC} to determine if 
it should be developed and incorporated to {PEBKAC}. <br> We will send you 
an E-mail saying if your suggestion
will be implemented or not. <br> <br>

This process could take up to a month to go through the cycle. <br> <br>

The {PEBKAC} Corporation would like to thank you for sharing your feeback 
 with us. <br> <br>

Keep in mind that when sending Feeback; it must comply with our <a 
 href="URL">Terms</a> 

<form action="mailto:EMAIL" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

<br>

Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="Username"><br> <br>

E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="E-mail"><br> <br>

Feedback:<br>
<input type="text" name="Feedback" size="20"> <br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
</div2>

</div>

</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
var i, x, tablinks;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   x[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-grey", ""); 
}
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " w3-grey";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed two closing tags `</div>` and `</form>` before the closing tag of `</div3>` in Contact Us tab.